# Facing an issue with Cucumber tags(Given,When,Then) and JUnit(Cucumber.class, Cucumber.Options(..)) with latest and old Cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber

I'm facing an issue related to Cucumber tags and Junit setup as there is difference between old and latest cucumber.

1. I'm using Cucumber 1.0.2 jar and Cucumber.Options(..)
2. I'm using Cucumber 1.2.2 jar and CucumberOptions(..)

In first case @Given, @When, @Then tags are working fine but facing issue with Cucumber.class and Cucumber.Options() in Junit setup.

In second case CucumberOptions(..) (updated one in latest version) is working fine and but issue with @Given, @When, @Then.

Can someone please provide the correct Cucumber tags and JUnit setup with respect to the jar version.

Case 1:
***pom.xml***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.2</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>  
<dependency> 
    <groupId>junit</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
    <version>4.10</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

***Junit Runner:***

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},tags= "@Smoketest")
public class JunitRunner {

}
```

Case2: ***pom.xml***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
    <version>1.2.2</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
 </dependency>  
 <dependency> 
    <groupId>junit</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
    <version>4.10</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
 </dependency>
```

***Junit Ruuner***

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},tags= "@Smoketest")
public class JunitRunner {

}
```

and with 1.2.2 facing issue with Cucumber tags as shown below:

[image: Click the image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use these imports ---

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
```

Comment: I think the packages you given are for 1.2.2. Am I corect? If yes, the Cucumber tags are fine but facing issues with JUnit runner setup with Cucmber.class

Comment: @RunWith(Cucumber.class). In this "Cucumber.class" is saying like, "Class<Cucumber> is not resolved to type". I just missed to import "cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;" package, which was not suggested to import on mouse hover.